# Custom Product HTML Template

Tags: product, products, product-page

My question is, i have a Overview as a Product for vices. This page is used to store 130 vices in one page. The problem is, i need to remove the price and the order button for this overview page. How can i do this without modifying the products page für every product?

http://duritec.ch/magento/din-931.html

Comment: My fix for this problem was, just making a html file which was named like the link and i've put it in the root folder. It worked, Magento is taking this html file instead of the generated method from itself.

Answer (score 1):

what about a custom layout calling a custom block rendering a custom template looking like the core product layout with some modifications?

Comment: I got another solution. I've took the generated html link and i placed a html file matching the links name in the root of magento, it worked! Magento is taking the html page in place of the xml's and phtml's generated page.

Answer (score 0):

Orion,

You can solve this with PHP or javaScript. Basically what you'll have to do is to create a conditional and show the information you want for that case. For example, let's say you want to hide information for product URL: din-931.html which by the way has an ID of let's say 8 so you would do:

```
<?php
   id = 8 // product id you want to hide information
   $variable = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();

if($variable !==8):?>
   <a href="" class="btn btn-primary>Shop Now</a>
<?php else:?>
   <a class="btn btn-primary>Call Us For More Info</a>
<?php endif:?>
```

Now you could do the same with product on category. Another way to do it is, if you see in your web inspector, you'll see that the body has the class product-din-931. You could do

```
.product-din-931 .add-to-cart {
    display:none;
}
```

But is all depends what you want to target, specific product or specific category. See more [here](http://www.eddiemay.me.uk/2011/11/07/magento-changing-the-body-class-by-category/) for categories. You could also add a custom attribute as dropdown for example Show Price Yes/No and show based on that.

PS: I noticed your URL is http://duritec.ch/magento/5x30.html this is terrible for SEO since you sell products, no magento related services.